# How to detect missing Source paths in XAML?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

I have a lot of `XAML` containing `Images` with `Source` set to various image files that a added as Resources to the project.

For example:

```
<Image  Source="/SiliconNervousSystem;component/icons/appbar.alert.png" Width="20">
```

Is there an easy way (or tool) to find ALL such Source paths in a Project/Solution?

Or even better, is there a way to find Source paths that are not valid (resource not present in the Project)? Building the solution will not detect if the Source path is present or not.

Many thanks,
pete

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following 2 Visual Studio tool window:`Live Visual Tree` and `Live Property Explorer`. Besides, it is also helpful for you to use UI Debugging Tool which is a small tool appearing at the top-center of your Xaml interface when debugging your app.

1. Firstly, you toggle `Enable selection` button on the UI Debugging Tool bar, select an element of UI, then `Live Visual Tree` will locate the corresponding item on the visual tree.
2. Right-click that item, select "Show properties" menu item, then `Live Property Explorer` tool window will appear, here you could verity its `DataContext` property.

If you cannot find `Live Visual Tree` tool window when debugging your app, just select "Debug" -> "Windows" -> "Live Visual Tree".

If you cannot see UI Debugging Tool, you can enable it: "Tool" -> "Options", select "Debugging" node, toggle on the "Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML"

Comment: I think he needs a way to check if images are missing **before** he runs the application, not detecting missing images during runtime.

Comment: I'm working on an extension that finds all image files (based on File Extension) in a solution. It then finds all Source values (for Images controls) from every XAML file. Finally, it checks to see what images are not used (Image file exists, but not Source refers to it) and what images are missing (Source refers to missing file)